# How can I use DefaultListModel to print data to JList?

Tags: java, jlist

I have these three methods and they work fine. I created fullInList to add the data from the ArrayList to the JList. But I want Java to read the file, and I want the data to be displayed in the JList. How can I do that?

```
ArrayList<PersonTest> person = new ArrayList<>();

DefaultListModel<PersonTest> model;
File fileName = new File("testFromClass.txt");
DefaultListModel<PersonTest> model2;


private void fillInList() {

    model = new DefaultListModel<>();

    for (PersonTest temp : person) {
        model.addElement(temp);
    }

    ListItems.setModel(model);
}

public void read(File fileN) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(fileN); 
    ObjectInputStream objeRead = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);

    while(inFile.available() > 0){          
        System.out.println((PersonTest) objeRead.readObject() + "\n");            
    }

    objeRead.close();
    System.out.println("File READ");

}

public void save(File fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream objOStram = 
             new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));

    for (int i = 0; i < person.size(); i++) {
        PersonTest p = person.get(i);
        objOStram.writeObject(p);
        objOStram.flush();

    }

    objOStram.close();
     System.out.println("File saved");

}
```

Comment: Have you actually added any `PersonTest` object to the `person` list? I don't see any addition in your code.

Comment: In your read(...) method you would need to create an ArrayList() before the loop starts. Then as you read each PersonTest you would add the object to the ArrayList. After the loop is finished you would invoke your "fillnList()" method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the PersonTest objects to the ArrayList that you use in the FillInList method, then when you call that method data will be available and will be inserted to the JList.